# create list of substrings of several lines

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Imagine I have the following list:

```
result_lines = ['name1 age1 address1 email1',
                'name2 age2 address2 email2',
                'name3 age3 address3 email3']
```

I would like to print the following string:

```
'age1:name1, age2:name2, age3: name3'
```

Note: no `,` at the end of the string!

**UPDATE**: important is not the order `age1:name1`. it could also be `age1:email1:name1`.

What I tried so far:

```
print "".join((l.split(' ')[1], l.split(' ')[0]) for l in result_lines)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pro tip: You do not need to use ``\`` continuation backslashes inside `[ .. ]`, `{ .. }` or `( .. )` pairs in Python. The parser knows you are not yet done when it hasn't found the balancing closing brace on the same line yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is your friend in a situation where you want to present the contents of a `list` or `tuple`:

```
>>> ', '.join(['{1}:{0}'.format(*line.split()) for line in result_lines])
'age1:name1, age2:name2, age3:name3'
```

To break this down a little, because there's a lot going on in that line...

We start with the simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [line for line in result_lines]
['name1 age1 address1 email1', 'name2 age2 address2 email2', 'name3 age3 address3 email3']
```

And split the string into whitespace using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (we only need to split *once*):

```
>>> [line.split() for line in result_lines]
[['name1', 'age1', 'address1', 'email1'], ['name2', 'age2', 'address2', 'email2'], ['name3', 'age3', 'address3', 'email3']]
```

Introduce [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [unpack the argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> ['{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}'.format(*line.split()) for line in result_lines]
['name1:age1:address1:email1', 'name2:age2:address2:email2', 'name3:age3:address3:email3']
```

Choose the elements we want:

```
>>> ['{1}:{0}'.format(*line.split()) for line in result_lines]
['age1:name1', 'age2:name2', 'age3:name3']
```

(`str.`)[`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) it all together with `', '`:

```
>>> ', '.join(['{1}:{0}'.format(*line.split()) for line in result_lines])
'age1:name1, age2:name2, age3:name3'
```

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 4):

To do this on one line without multiple calls to split you need to reverse and slice the `.split()` result, and nest your string joins:

```
', '.join([':'.join(line.split()[:2][::-1]) for line in result_lines])
```

So each entry in the list is:

- Split on whitespace
- Sliced to only give the name and age entries
- Reversed so age comes before name using `[::-1]` to reverse in-place.
- Joined with `':'` to give the `age?:name?` pairs.
- We use a list comprehension (`[ ... for .. in ... ]`) because that's faster with `str.join()`. Internally, `.join()` calculates the final string length before joining and will cast a generator to a list *anyway*. The comprehension then wins on speed.

Then the whole list is joined with `', '` to give a nice comma-separated list. Because we only split *once* this will run

This gives:

```
>>> ', '.join([':'.join(line.split()[:2][::-1]) for line in result_lines])
'age1:name1, age2:name2, age3:name3'
```

Comment: +1: While I think my solution is more readable, this is an excellent explanation (particularly regarding `str.join()` and `list`s, which I did not know).

Comment: Why does `.join` _need_ to calculate the final string length?

Comment: @wim: it allocates the final C string size. Not doing so would require re-allocating a new string for every element in the input list minus one. That is *very* inefficient.

Comment: OK, so that can explain how it _does_ work.  But that doesn't mean it _needs_ to, it could for example iterate and join, doubling the allocation size when necessary.. couldn't it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  +1 for the nice explanation, although it is not exactly what I was looking for (sorry for my imprecise question)

Comment: @wim: If you can show that that would be more efficient in a variety of cases, I'm sure the Python dev team would be delighted to adjust the code! I haven't run any comparisons on that, but I suspect that the cost of calculating the size up-front could be cheaper in many cases than doubling the allocation dynamically, then shrink once completed.

Comment: @ezdazuzena: Ah, yes, in that case Johns solution will beat mine hands-down. :-) String formatting with `.format()` is very powerful like that!

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that using a genex was actually _slower_ in this situation!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
>>> result_lines = ['name1 age1 address1 email1', \
...                 'name2 age2 address2 email2', \
...                 'name3 age3 address3 email3']
>>> print ", ".join([l.split(' ')[1] + ': ' + l.split(' ')[0] for l in result_lines])
age1: name1, age2: name2, age3: name3
```